# Pass props created in app.jsx level through react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have an react/redux app where I am trying to pass some props into my components. Right now in my app.jsx I just have a pretty straight forward render like so :

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router
      history={browserHistory}
      >
      {routes}
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

the {routes} just looks like

```
export default(
  <Route component={App} path="/">
    <Route component={MyComponent} path="/" />
  </Route>
);
```

And I just want to pass some props to that App component. The first thing I tried was like so :

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router
      history={browserHistory}
      passedProp={passedProp}
      >
      {routes}
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

So I am trying to effectively get `this.props.passedProp` inside of that App component. I tried googling around and a few other things and can't seem to come up with the correct solution. Is there a correct way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't something like `this.props.router.props.passedProp` or `this.props.router.passedProp` work inside of App with your current setup?

Comment: Where are you trying to pass the props from? Also, side note, why two components that both use path `/`?

Answer (score 0):

You would do it in your `mapStateToProps` function of `AppComponent.jsx` (assuming in your routes you use `import App from './AppComponent.jsx'`. We could provide more help if you told some more details of where `passedprop` comes from and how it's used.

Here's the react-router docs on what you can do in `<Route>`: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#route

Answer (score 0):

## react-router 4

you can pass props directly to the component using the `Match` component and the `component` prop.

The code example below is passing the custom props `label` and `title` to the `Game` component.

```
const route = {
    pattern: '/game',
    label: 'Star Wars Trivia',
    title: `${siteTitle} - Star Wars Trivia`,
    component: Game
  };
<Match { ...route } key={ i } render={(props) => <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes}/>} />
```

for a working example app, checkout [react-lego](https://github.com/peter-mouland/react-lego) and the [routes.js on the react-router-4 branch](https://github.com/peter-mouland/react-lego/blob/react-router-4/src/app/routes.js)